# Alias in local apache install

Tags: apache, url

I have an apache install on my local machine and my project is located at:

```
http://localhost/my/dir/
```

and I would like to access it by typing:

```
http://projectname/
```

How is this achieved in apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll need to create a virtualhost. Take a look at this:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html

Secondly, you will need to add an entry into your hosts file to point projectname to localhost.